# facing issue to start react application npm start error

Tags: reactjs, npm, env-cmd

when I issue below command to start react app facing this error, can anyone help.
npm start

> react_template@0.1.0 start
> env-cmd -f .env.dev craco start

'env-cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: >npm start

> react_template@0.1.0 start
> env-cmd -f .env.dev craco start

'env-cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: please provide your `package.json` file so we can see the packages you have installed. From this we are not able to tell the problem. (Edit your question to include the file in code blocks please)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install cross-env with npm? Try running

```
npm install
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

its really hard to tell without taking a look at your package.json file. but i see that you're using env-cmd package which provides custom run and build commands and lets you have multiple environment declarations.
here is an example of what you can do with it in your package.json (this example is a nextjs example)

```
"scripts": {

    "dev": "env-cmd -f env/.env.local next dev",

    "build:pre": "env-cmd -f env/.env.pre next build",

    "start:pre": "env-cmd -f env/.env.pre next start",

    "build:stg": "env-cmd -f env/.env.stg next build",

    "start:stg": "env-cmd -f env/.env.stg next start",

    "build:rc": "env-cmd -f env/.env.rc next build",

    "start:rc": "env-cmd -f env/.env.rc next start",

    "build:prod": "env-cmd -f env/.env.prod next build",

    "start:prod": "env-cmd -f env/.env.prod next start"

  },
```

as you can see i created a build and run command for each environment and i also provided a .env.ENVNAME file for my config. the env/,env.ENVNAME is the path of my .env files. the env folder is in the root of the project.
here is how to run and build the app with env-cmd for above scripts:

npm run build:Env_name
for example for building my stg env:
npm run build:stg

or for starting the app
npm run start:Env_name
for example:
npm run start:stg

in your local you can use npm run dev to run the application and npm run build to build it.